# How to use jQuery to call a servlet with multiple non distinct URL params?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a servlet that needs a call like http://localhost:8080?a=1&a=3&a=2&b=5. The thing is it has multiple params with the same name like 'a' here. How can I generate such a servlet query. I used this for distinct param names.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080',
  data: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  success: function(response) {
  }
});
```

But what can I do when the param names are not distinct? I need the outgoing GET to look like shown above and not in some serialized format for it to be compatible with the servlet (which I cant modify)

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the ajax data option as a string,
So in your case you want

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080',
  data: "a=1&a=3&a=2&b=5",
  success: function(response) {
  }
});
```

How you go about defining that string I'll leave to you :)

EDIT: Formatting

Comment: I confirm that this works and I can also confirm that it is clever :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "traditional: true" flag in the jquery.ajax [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  I've had to set it to true when I've had multiple form fields with the same name and it wasn't playing nice with MVC2.

Comment: I was originally going to suggest that but reading the description I got the impression that http://localhost:8080?a[]=1&a[]=3&a[]=2&b=5 (notice the []'s) wouldn't work.

Comment: @Jeff T thanks for this post.  This answer is so much simpler